# How to restrict one number in 1-100 auto generate JavaScript

Tags: javascript, numbers, generator

I want to restrict one number for example 34 in this number generator. When someone generates a number with a button click, never coincides with a restricted number for example 34.

```js
function IsNumeric(n) {
    return !isNaN(n);
}
$(function () {
    $("#getit").click(function () {
        let numLow = $("#lownumber").val();
        let numHigh = $("#highnumber").val();

        let adjustedHigh = (parseFloat(numHigh) - parseFloat(numLow)) + 1;

        let numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * adjustedHigh) + parseFloat(numLow);

        if ((IsNumeric(numLow)) && (IsNumeric(numHigh)) && (parseFloat(numLow) <= parseFloat(numHigh)) && (numLow !== '') && (numHigh !== '')) {
            $("#randomnumber").text(numRand);
        } else {
            $("#randomnumber").text("Careful now...");
        }
        return false;
    });

    let input = $("input[type=text]");
    
    input.each(function () {
        $(this).data("first-click", true);
    });

    input.focus(function () {
        if ($(this).data("first-click")) {
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).data("first-click", false);
            $(this).css("color", "black");
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page-wrap">
        
        <input type="text" id="lownumber" value="1" />
        
        <input type="text" id="highnumber" value="100" />
        
        <br />
        
        <button id="getit">Generate!</button>
        
        <div id="randomnumber"></div>
    
    </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a conditional check to make sure the generated number is not the restricted number:

```
var numRand = 0, restrictedNumber = 34;      
do {
    numRand = Math.floor(Math.random()*adjustedHigh) + parseFloat(numLow);
} while (numRand == restrictedNumber);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JHhDx/

You'll probably also want to add something to check to make sure the restricted number is also not the only possible number

Comment: Ou Thank you so much... It's exactly what i wanted... Thanks :)))

Comment: This is definitely the nice and concise answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Besides a loop, you could also make a recursive function.

http://jsfiddle.net/chucknelson/eYAy6/2/

```
var userRestrictedNum = 34; //could get this from input    

function getit(restrictedNum) {
        ...random number code...

        if(numRand != restrictedNum) {
            return numRand;
        }
        else {
            return getit(restrictedNum);
        }
    }

    $("#getit").click(function() {
        $("#randomnumber").text(getit(userRestrictedNum));
    });
```

Comment: i have one question is there way, this generated number to be <input> value?

Comment: If you keep your random number generation in a function, just set the value of an input as the return value (e.g., $('#myinput').val(getit(restrictedNum));).

Comment: ok i figured it out after $("#randomnumber").text(numRand); this line i put your idea like that $('#myinput').val(numRand); an made input in html and it worls perfectly... thank you very much